# Looking for Node.js easy tutorial for a multiplayer game creation (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, html5-canvas

After googling for 2 hours I still havent found and easy Node.JS communicating with javascript tutorial. I would really just like to see a very simple application that for example presses a button and completes one simple task by using a canvas element or whatever. Could anyone give me an example/tutorial of a very basic Node.js application using socket.io. This is my first experience with Node.js and I just want an easy example that works and build from that.

Edit: I'm using appfog.com for my node.js server I take it I can use this externally?

Comment: What does Socket.IO have to do with drawing on a canvas?  Can you clarify your question?

Comment: "Socket.IO is a JavaScript library for realtime web applications." - I take it socket.io is what I need to create a fluit multiplayer game cant find any other realtime libraries for javascript/node.js

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be a trend with brand-new stackoverflow users looking for "simple/easy/basic" examples of real-time, multiuser, distributed network applications. Here's the truth: realtime, distributed, multiuser, network applications **ARE NOT SIMPLE**. Can you build `Hello, World!` in node? If not, start there. Can you deploy a web application that queries a database and puts some data from the database into an HTML page? Demonstrate that, and maybe acquire some rep on this site in the process. Less googling. More coding. Don't start from a working application and tweak. You are setting yourself up for crippling knowledge gaps that will hamper you endlessly until you go back and fill them in. Start from a single empty `.js` file and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

completely agree with Peter Lyons.
I understand your condition inControl.
I myself started with the node recently and even tried to do some hacks and fetch some patches of code from here and there but honestly I found that this will not work so then I found a very good book on the same which is 
Node Cookbook.
So I would recommend you the same.
First try to understand the inner architecture of the NODE technology which is a must to build any good application on the node, without understanding it you will surely find yourself in a mess of all callback functions in future.
In the above mentioned book you will also find some very good modules mentioned by the author which will guide you from start to the end.